# get-wmiobject to kill the process using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Need help! I want to kill the particular (ex: iexplore ) running process for particular owner ( iexplore may initiated by many users but I want to kill the iexplore for particular user ) using `powershell`.

can any one help me on this. Advance thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use this code

```
$UserName = “Username”
$PCName = “PCName.domain”
$ProcessName = "iexplore.exe"
(Get-WmiObject win32_process -ComputerName $PCName| where{$_.getowner().user -eq $UserName -and $_.ProcessName -eq $ProcessName}).Terminate()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the wmi class win32_process

`stop-process (gwmi win32_process |
    ?{$_.getOwner().user -eq "username" -and $_.name -match "iexplore"} |
    select -expand processid) -WhatIf #remove -whatif to effectively stop the process`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. when i run this , i am getting the error.

Exception calling "GetOwner" : "Not found "
At line:1 char:38
+ stop-process (gwmi win32_process | ?{$_.getOwner().user -eq "gssmboop" -and $_.n ...
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WMIMethodException